# android html5 app is blank

Tags: android, html, intel, intel-xdk

I am new to this...

I am using Intel XDK

I created a default page in PHP but when I upload it I got:

**404: Intel XDK can't find your app Do you have index.html in your application directory?**

I tried html page whch redirects to php like this:

**http://www.jassimrahma.com/yalla.bahrain/index.php" />**

but it's just shown as blank page on Android.

I upload the pages on my hot as well and I didn't have any issue there. this is the url

http://www.jassimrahma.com/yalla.bahrain/index.html

how can I solve this please..

Comment: post the code that is redirecting to webpage

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the content of webpage to show up in app, you can create a blank project and set:

```
window.location = "http://www.jassimrahma.com/yalla.bahrain/index.php";
```

Below is entire index.html file, this will work in XDK and you will be able to build Android app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XDK</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />
    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.location = "http://www.jassimrahma.com/yalla.bahrain/index.php";        
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);               
        function onDeviceReady(){
            intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();   
        }
    </script>            
</head>
<body> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not only your problem. It is a bug in Intel XDK.

[image]

We just have to wait until they fix it...

What I have being doing, is to close and reopen the Intel XDK... Yes, it´s a bit annoying...

[More information here.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/544927#comment-1829924)